# React native maps jumps back to region on release

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I use react-native maps - Mapview in my React Native app. On Android, the code works as expected, the location of the user is used to determine the region. This will be included in this.state.latitude and this.state.longtitude. Only on iOS I have the problem that when I 'scroll' on the map it jumps back to the region after releasing it. If I put the code on initialRegion I end up somewhere in a sea and the user has to scroll indefinitely. Does anybody have experience with this?

after setting code to initialRoute:

[image]

The current code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View,ScrollView, SafeAreaView, ImageBackground, Button,TouchableOpacity, Alert, Image, Linking, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { ListItem, ThemeConsumer } from 'react-native-elements'
import { Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";
//import { ClusterMap } from "react-native-cluster-map";
import MapView from "react-native-map-clustering";
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import LaunchNavigator from 'react-native-launch-navigator';

if(Platform.OS === "android") LaunchNavigator.setGoogleApiKey("API KEY");


class locationScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {

            cities : [ ],
            totalStores: 0,
            latitude:0,
            longitude: 0,
            nearestPlace: null,

        }
    }

    deg2Rad = (deg) => {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
      }

      pythagorasEquirectangular = (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) => {
        lat1 = this.deg2Rad(lat1);
        lat2 = this.deg2Rad(lat2);
        lon1 = this.deg2Rad(lon1);
        lon2 = this.deg2Rad(lon2);
        const R = 6371;
        const x = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2);
        const y = (lat2 - lat1);
        const d = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) * R;
        return d;
      }
      nearestCity = (latitude, longitude) => {
       let mindif = 99999;
       let closest;


       for (let index = 0; index < this.state.cities.length; index++) {

        const dif = this.pythagorasEquirectangular(latitude, longitude, this.state.cities[index].lat, 
          this.state.cities[index].long);
          if (dif < mindif) {
          closest = index;
          mindif = dif;
          }

        }

        this.setState({
           nearestPlace: closest,

        })

        this.state.cities.forEach(i =>{
            if( i.name == this.state.cities[this.state.nearestPlace].name) i.nearest = 1 ;
          })

          this.setState({
            cities: this.state.cities,
          })

       // this.nearestPlace = closest
       // return cities= closest;
      }
    navigateTo = (item) => {
        console.log(item.street);
      LaunchNavigator.navigate(item.street + "," + item.zip+ ","+ item.city)
        .then(() => console.log("Launched navigator"))
        .catch((err) => console.error("Error launching navigator: "+err));
    }

    setCurrentDirections = () =>{

        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
          this.setState({
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            desLat: position.coords.latitude,
            desLong: position.coords.longitude,
            error: null,
          });
          console.log("reached function");
          console.log("latitude: "  + this.state.latitude);
          console.log("Longtitude: "  + this.state.longitude);
        })

      }

    setNearestonClick= (clickId) =>{

        this.state.cities.forEach(i =>{
            if( i.name == clickId) i.nearest = 1 ;
          })

          this.setState({
            cities: this.state.cities,
          })
    }

    onItemClickHandler= (url)=>{
        Linking.openURL(url)
    }

   /* PressedLocation = (data) =>{
        console.log('location:' + data.lat + 'long ' +data.long );
        this.setState({
            latitude: data.lat,
            longitude: data.long,
            error: null,
          });

    }
*/

        markerCliked = (id) =>{
            console.log("id is: " + id);
        }

    latitude= 0;
    longitude= 0;
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setCurrentDirections();

        let ref = firebase.database().ref('stores');
        ref.on('value' , snapshot =>{
            var state = snapshot.val();

            this.setState({
                cities: state,
                totalStores: state.length,
            })

            this.nearestCity(this.state.latitude, this.state.longitude);
        })
    }

    render(){
        const { cities } = this.state;
        return(

            <ScrollView style={styles.scorllVert}>
                <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.headerLeft}> 
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menubar} onPress={this.props.navigation.openDrawer}>
                            <Icon name="bars" size={24}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.headerCenter}> 
                    <Image source={require('./assets/images/all/logo-snackpoint.png')} style={styles.logoSnackpoint} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.headerRight}> 
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.userIcon}>
                            <Icon name="user-circle" size={24} onPress={this.props.navigation.openDrawer}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </SafeAreaView>

                <View style={styles.headerStores}> 
                        <Text  style={styles.headerStoresText}>Aantal vestigingen: {this.state.totalStores}</Text>
                    </View>
                <View style={styles.containerContent}>


                    <View style={styles.page}>
                    <View style={styles.containerMap}>
                    <MapView
                    showsUserLocation={true}

                            style={{ flex: 1 }}
                            onClusterPress={() => this.markerCliked()}
                            region={{
                                latitude: this.state.latitude,
                                longitude: this.state.longitude,
                                latitudeDelta: 0.015,
                                longitudeDelta: 0.0121
                            }}
                            >
                        {
                                    this.state.cities.map(marker => (
                                        <Marker key={marker.name}  coordinate={{latitude: marker.lat, longitude: marker.long}} onPress={() => this.setNearestonClick(marker.name)}/>
                                    ))

                        }

                    </MapView>
                    </View>
                    </View>

                <View style={styles.stores}>

                {
                    this.state.cities.sort(function(a, b) {
                        if(a.nearest) return -1;
                        if(b.nearest) return 1;
                        if(a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
                        if(a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
                        return 0;
                       }).map((marker, i) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.navigateTo(marker)} >
                    <View style={styles.store}> 
                        <View style={styles.leftcolumn}> 
                            <Text style={styles.storeTitle}>{marker.name}</Text>
                            <Text>{marker.street}</Text>
                            <Text>{marker.zip}, {marker.city}</Text>
                            <Text>Telefoon: {marker.phone}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.midcolumn}> 
                            <Text>Ma:</Text>
                            <Text>Di:</Text>
                            <Text>Wo:</Text>
                            <Text>Do:</Text>
                            <Text>Vr:</Text>
                            <Text>Za:</Text>
                            <Text>Zo:</Text>
                        </View> 
                        <View style={styles.rightcolumn}> 
                            <Text>{marker.monday}</Text>
                            <Text>{marker.tuesday}</Text>
                            <Text>{marker.wednesday}</Text>
                            <Text>{marker.thursday}</Text>
                            <Text>{marker.friday}</Text>
                            <Text>{marker.saturday}</Text>
                            <Text>{marker.sunday}</Text>
                        </View> 

                    </View>
                    <View style={{borderBottomColor: '#C8C8C8',borderBottomWidth: 1,}}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    ))
                }
                </View>




                </View>


            </ScrollView>

        )
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      alignItems: 'flex-start',
        marginBottom: 13
    },
    text:{
        color: "#161924",
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: "500",
    },userIcon:{
        paddingTop: 22,
        paddingRight: 0,
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
    },
    logoSnackpoint:{
        width: 180,
        height: 52,
        marginTop: 12,
    },
    headerLeft:{
        width: '33%',
    },
    headerCenter:{
        width: '30%',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    headerRight:{
        width: '30%',
    },
    menubar:{
        paddingTop: 22,
        paddingLeft: 20
    },

    containerContent:{
        padding: 0,
        paddingBottom: 30
    },
    title:{
        fontSize: 35
    },
    textTitle:{
        marginTop: 10,
    },
    titleRed:{
        fontSize: 25,
        color: '#CC2929',
        marginTop: 30,
        marginBottom: 10
    },
    map: {
        flex: 1
      },
      page: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
      },
      containerMap: {
        height: 300,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: "tomato"
      },
      headerStores:{
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: '#CD2929',
          textAlign: 'center',
          paddingTop: 20,
          paddingBottom: 20
      },
      headerStoresText:{
          color: 'white',
          textAlign: 'center'
      },
      store:{

        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        width: '100%',
        padding: 20
      },
        leftcolumn:{
        width: "50%",
        },
        midcolumn:{
        width: "20%",
        },
        rightcolumn:{
        width: "30%",
        },
        storeTitle:{
            color: '#CD2929',
            fontWeight: "bold",
            fontSize: 30
        },
        hr:{
            backgroundColor: 'grey',
            padding: 5
        }



  });

  export default locationScreen;
```

Comment: Can you share it on expo.snack.io?

Comment: unfortunately I can't get it on there, but you want to see what the problem is or what?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with maps before in ios/Android without any issues

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that there is a problem when setting the `region` property within the MapView.

From my code, I removed the part that looks like this from the MapView

```
region=
{{
   latitude: this.state.latitude,
   longitude: this.state.longitude,
   latitudeDelta: 0.015,
   longitudeDelta: 0.0121
}}
```

and I can scroll back again.

But then, you'll have to find a way to set the region, it looks buggy with this component. Especially with class components.

Answer (score 0):

`initialRegion` is uncontrolled state, the map will only set to the region on initial load, so if you set it before your region is defined it will focus on `lat:0, lng: 0` -- out in the ocean. So before you render your map, make sure the region is defined.

`region` is controlled state, as the map redraws it will use the most recent region definition. If you drag the map, and the region doesn't update doesn't get updated to the new location, the next redraw of the map will go to whatever the region was last defined as. `handleRegionChangeComplete` can be used to update the region as you move, but you can run into jumpiness if multiple redraws are occurring at the same time.